# Return iterable of unpackable values that won't break client code if I start returning more data

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

Let's say you're writing an API you intend to make public. A function `quux` in your API returns a list or a generator of tuples, e.g. `yield (foo, bar)`.

The client code would typically use it like this:

```
for foo, bar in quux(whatever):
    # do stuff with foo and bar
```

Now, suppose that in the future you might want to start returning `baz` together with `foo` and `bar`. You don't want to return it right now, because YAGNI until proven otherwise.

What would be the best way to (try to) make sure future changes like that won't break client code?

I know that Python 3 allows people to do stuff like `for foo, bar, *idontcare in quux(whatever)` and in Python 2 one could always write a utility function (to use like this `for foo, bar in iterleft(quux(whatever), 2)`):

```
def iterleft(iterable, limit):
    for item in iterable:
        yield item[:limit]
```

But I was wondering whether there was a better way to do stuff like this.

Comment: 'destructuring' is more of a closure and javascript 1.7 term; in python we call it tuple unpacking.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at 'unpacking' and didn't think of looking for 'tuple-unpacking' :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead of a regular tuple, and you don't need to unpack it. You can then later *extend* the returned tuple without affecting existing users of the API:

```
from collections import namedtuple

QuuxReturnValue = namedtuple('QuuxReturnValue', ('foo', 'bar'))

def quux(*args, **kw):
    while True:
        yield QuuxReturnValue(foo='foo', bar='bar')
```

and your API is consumed like:

```
for retval in quux():
    print retval.foo, retval.bar
```

If you later update the `namedtuple` to add a 3rd parameter `'baz'` the above consumer is still going to work.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have semantic data ("the first element of the tuple means x, the second element means y, ...") which you are not passing with the data.

A generic way to solve this is to return a dictionary `{"foo": foo, "bar": bar, ...}` of parameters. Of course, then you can't use tuple unpacking.

Otherwise, to preserve backwards compatibility you can't change `quux`. Instead, you can write `quux_with_bar` that yields `(foo, bar, baz)` tuples and then make `quux` just filter the first two elements of that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think returning a `namedtuple` is an excellent idea because the return value wouldn't need unpacking.

Comment: @martineau: indeed, made it into an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I was going to if you didn't... ;-)